# how can I properly enable android.databinding library in my android project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-databinding

I want to use ObservableList, so I follow [this instruction](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/databinding), adding the code below on my (Module:app)build.gradle and Syns:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Yeah, it works. I can import ObservableList to my class now. But the question is, when I run the app, a compile exception(NullPointException) occurs:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp">


<com.example.lj032.myapplication.MyGridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously, the issue was caused by databingding library, according to the log. But I have no idea how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I properly Enable dataBinding

Inside `Build.gradle(:app)`

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

Dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.5.1'
```

Bind your xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="DataModel" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="@{item.name}"/>// binding data from model

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

P.S: do not forget to add plugin in `Build.gradle(:app)`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

After doing all above step sync and rebuild project

Comment: Should I have to change every XML file in my project? There are dozens of XML files......I can't image I edit them one by one.....

Comment: No . Only those in which you want to use dataBinding. It will not effect any other layout

Comment: Eh....Still a big work....Another question: when I add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and Syns, it says "Plugin with id 'kotlin-kapt' not found". Is that plugin necessary?

Comment: If you are using kotlin based project YES else No